# Populate missing months forward filling

Tags: r, dplyr

I work with a data sample, which is similar to the structure below:

```
  ID Date           Score
  1  10.02.2012     5
  1  10.05.2012     5
  2  01.09.2016     8
  2  10.10.2016     8
  3  08.02.2015     3
  3  02.04.2015     3
```

I wish to somehow transform ist to the following form:

```
  ID     Date        Score
  1      02.2012     5
  1      03.2012     5
  1      04.2012     5
  1      05.2012     5
  2      09.2016     8
  2      10.2016     8
  3      02.2015     3
  3      03.2015     3
  3      04.2015     3
```

Firstly, I converted character date into date format by executing:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,format="%d.%m.%Y")
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% complete(seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by="months"))
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Any idea how to fix the problem would be highly appreciated!

To replicate the case use data below:

```
    df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), Date = structure(c(15380, 
15470, 17045, 17084, 16474, 16527), class = "Date"), Score = c(5, 
5, 8, 5, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just a typo. You need to define `Date = seq.Date(...)`, i.e.  `...complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "months"))`

Comment: `Date` column should keep `Date` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr`'s `fill`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date + 10), by="months")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  fill(Score) %>% 
  mutate(Date = gsub("-", ".", format(as.Date(Date), "%m-%Y")))
```

what leads yo:

```
## A tibble: 9 x 3
#     ID Date    Score
#  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#1     1 02.2012     5
#2     1 03.2012     5
#3     1 04.2012     5
#4     1 05.2012     5
#5     2 09.2016     8
#6     2 10.2016     8
#7     3 02.2015     3
#8     3 03.2015     3
#9     3 04.2015     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `dput()` differs from your example.

You can use `as.yearmon()` from `zoo` in order for the format, plus `na.locf()` to fill missings.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "months")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(Score = na.locf(Score, na.rm=T),
         type = na.locf(type, na.rm=T))
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
# ID Date          type  Score
# <dbl> <S3: yearmon> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 feb 2012      a         5
# 2     1 mar 2012      a         5
# 3     1 apr 2012      a         5
# 4     1 mag 2012      b         5
# 5     2 set 2016      a         8
# 6     2 ott 2016      a         8
# 7     2 nov 2016      a         8
# 8     2 dic 2016      a         8
# 9     3 feb 2015      a         3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  select(ID, Date, Score) %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  complete(month = full_seq(month,1), Score)
```